# Cloud Builder can't connect with Git via ssh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I generated ssh keys and added as in the manual (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos#create_or_update_known_hosts_file) but when the builder uses the command `git submodule update --init --recursive` I'm getting:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

When I'm using same ssh keys localy I dont have any problems with cloning repos etc.